# Missing node when using Tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, missing

I am using the Tikz package to create a flow chart in LaTeX. When I compile the code below I get two errors:

1. The node for Group 1b (and the nodes below it) that derives from Level B1 is missing from the diagram.
2. Instead, the arrow that should go from Level B1 to Group 1b, now goes from Level B1 to to Group 2a, which should not happen. Group 2a should only be connected to Level B2 and the nodes below it.

I think if I am able to resolve error 1., then error 2. should go away. What can I do to get the Group 1b node to show?

Thank you.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp!]
    \centering
    \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4cm, auto]

% Place nodes
    \node [block] (A) {\textit{Level A}};
    \node [block, left of= A] (G1) {\textbf{Group 1}};
    \node [block, right of= A] (G2) {\textbf{Group 2}};
    \node [block, below of= G1] (B) {\textit{Level B1}};
    \node [block, left of= B] (G1a) {\textbf{Group 1a}};
    \node [block, below of= G1a] (G1aD1) {Decision 1};
    \node [block, below of= G1aD1] (G1aD2) {Decision 2};
    \node [block, right of= B] (G1b) {\textbf{Group 1b}};
    \node [block, below of= G1b] (G1bD1) {Decision 1};
    \node [block, below of= G1bD1] (G1bD2) {Decision 2};
    \node [block, below of= G2] (C) {\textit{Level B2}};
    \node [block, left of= C] (G2a) {\textbf{Group 2a}};
    \node [block, below of= G2a] (G2aD1) {Decision 1};
    \node [block, below of= G2aD1] (G2aD2) {Decision 2};
    \node [block, right of= C] (G2b) {\textbf{Group 2b}};
    \node [block, below of= G2b] (G2bD1) {Decision 1};
    \node [block, below of= G2bD1] (G2bD2) {Decision 2};

% Draw lines
    \path [line, dashed] (A) -- (G1);
    \path [line, dashed] (A) -- (G2);
    \path [line, dashed] (G1) -- (B);
    \path [line, dashed] (G2) -- (C);
    \path [line, dashed] (B) -- (G1a);
    \path [line, dashed] (B) -- (G1b); 
    \path [line, dashed] (C) -- (G2a);
    \path [line, dashed] (C) -- (G2b);
    \path [line] (G1a) -- (G1aD1);
    \path [line] (G1b) -- (G1bD1); QQQ
    \path [line] (G1aD1) -- (G1aD2);
    \path [line] (G1bD1) -- (G1bD2); 
    \path [line] (G2a) -- (G2aD1);
    \path [line] (G2b) -- (G2bD1);
    \path [line] (G2aD1) -- (G2aD2);
    \path [line] (G2bD1) -- (G2bD2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Flow Chart}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variation of @frougon answer: used are `chains` packages and its macro `join`. Both enables to write a bit shorter code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning, 
                shapes}

\tikzset{
     block/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!20,
                     minimum height=4em, text width=5em,
                     align=center},
every join/.style = {draw, -stealth},
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 8mm and 12mm, 
  start chain = going below,
        nodes = {block, on chain}, 
                        ]
% Place nodes
% central column
\node       (A)     {Level A};
\node       (G2a)   {\textbf{Group 2a}};
\node[join] (G2aD1) {Decision 1};
\node[join] (G2aD2) {Decision 2};
%% left columns
\node[left=of A] (G1)   {\textbf{Group 1}};
\node[font=\itshape] (B){Level B1};
\node       (G1b)   {\textbf{Group 1b}};
\node[join] (G1bD1) {Decision 1};
\node[join] (G1bD2) {Decision 2};
%
\node[left=of B] (G1a) {\textbf{Group 1a}};
\node[join] (G1aD1) {Decision 1};
\node[join] (G1aD2) {Decision 2};
%% right columns
\node[right=of A] (G2)  {\textbf{Group 2}};
\node[font=\itshape] (C){Level B2};
%
\node[right=of C] (G2b) {\textbf{Group 2b}};
\node[join] (G2bD1)     {Decision 1};
\node[join] (G2bD2)     {Decision 2};
% dashed arrows
\draw[-stealth, dashed]   
    (A)  edge (G1) 
    (A)  edge (G2)
    (G1) edge (B)
    (G2) edge (C)
    (B)  edge (G1a)
    (B)  edge (G1b)
    (C)  edge (G2a)
    (C)  edge (G2b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

result is:

[image]

**Addendum:**
Hierarchy of nodes is better visible in the following placement of nodes:

[image]

Using the same concept of image drawing as at the first example, the MWE is:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning, 
                shapes}

\tikzset{
     block/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!20,
                     minimum height=4em, text width=5em,
                     align=center},
every join/.style = {draw, -stealth},
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 8mm and 8mm, 
  start chain = going below,
        nodes = {block, on chain}, 
                        ]
% Place nodes
\node (A)   {Level A};
%% left columns
    \node[below  left=16mm of A] (G1)  {\textbf{Group 1}};
    \node[font=\itshape] (B)    {Level B1};
        \node[below  left=of B.south]  (G1a)   {\textbf{Group 1a}};
            \node[join] (G1aD1) {Decision 1};
            \node[join] (G1aD2) {Decision 2};
        \node[below right=of B.south]  (G1b)   {\textbf{Group 1b}};
            \node[join] (G1bD1) {Decision 1};
            \node[join] (G1bD2) {Decision 2};
    \node[below right=16mm of A] (G2)  {\textbf{Group 2}};
    \node[font=\itshape] (C){Level B2};
        \node[below  left=of C.south]     (G2a)   {\textbf{Group 2a}};
            \node[join] (G2aD1) {Decision 1};
            \node[join] (G2aD2) {Decision 2};
        \node[below right=of C.south] (G2b) {\textbf{Group 2b}};
            \node[join] (G2bD1)     {Decision 1};
            \node[join] (G2bD2)     {Decision 2};
% dashed arrows
    \begin{scope}[every path/.style={-stealth, dashed}]
\draw   (A)  -| (G1)    (G2) edge (C);        
\draw   (A)  -| (G2)    (G1) edge (B);
\draw (B)  -| (G1a);
\draw (B)  -| (G1b);
\draw (C)  -| (G2a);
\draw (C)  -| (G2b);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This diagram is simpler to drawn with `forest` package (see answer of @Schrödinger's cat).

**Addendum (2):**
For fun and exercise ... less sophisticated with some (small) modification of @Schrödinger's cat answer (+1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
% nodes
    draw, rounded corners,
    fill=blue!20,
    minimum height=4em, text width=5em,
    text centered,
% distance between nodes
    s sep=12mm,
    l sep=8mm,
% edges
if={level>3}{edge={-stealth},
             edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
                (!u.south) -- (.child anchor);}
             }
             {edge={-stealth,dashed},
        where level={2}{font=\itshape}{% edges outside level 2
            edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
                (!u) -| (.child anchor);},
                                      }
            },% end of dashed edges definitions
% fonts
    where level={1}{font=\bfseries}{},
    where level={3}{font=\bfseries}{},
        }% end of "for tree"
% diagram body
[Level A
    [Group 1
        [Level B1
            [Group 1a
                [Decision 1
                    [Decision 2]
                ]
            ]
            [Group 1b
                [Decision 1
                    [Decision 2]
                ]
            ]
        ]
 ]  
    [Group 2
        [Level B2
            [Group 2a
                [Decision 1
                    [Decision 2]
                ]
            ]
            [Group 2b
                [Decision 1
                    [Decision 2]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Your node G1b containing `\textbf{Group 1b}` was hidden behind node G2a containing `\textbf{Group 2a}`, because you placed G1b with `right of= B`. Changing this placement specification to `below of= B` gives the following output. I also replaced your `\tikzstyle` commands with `\tikzset`, because `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows}

\tikzset{
  decision/.style={
    diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node
    distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt},
  block/.style={
    rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text centered,
    rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
  line/.style={draw, -latex'},
}

\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4cm, auto]

% Place nodes
\node [block] (A) {\textit{Level A}};
\node [block, left of= A] (G1) {\textbf{Group 1}};
\node [block, right of= A] (G2) {\textbf{Group 2}};
\node [block, below of= G1] (B) {\textit{Level B1}};
\node [block, left of= B] (G1a) {\textbf{Group 1a}};
\node [block, below of= G1a] (G1aD1) {Decision 1};
\node [block, below of= G1aD1] (G1aD2) {Decision 2};
\node [block, below of= B] (G1b) {\textbf{Group 1b}};
\node [block, below of= G1b] (G1bD1) {Decision 1};
\node [block, below of= G1bD1] (G1bD2) {Decision 2};
\node [block, below of= G2] (C) {\textit{Level B2}};
\node [block, left of= C] (G2a) {\textbf{Group 2a}};
\node [block, below of= G2a] (G2aD1) {Decision 1};
\node [block, below of= G2aD1] (G2aD2) {Decision 2};
\node [block, right of= C] (G2b) {\textbf{Group 2b}};
\node [block, below of= G2b] (G2bD1) {Decision 1};
\node [block, below of= G2bD1] (G2bD2) {Decision 2};

% Draw lines
\path [line, dashed] (A) -- (G1);
\path [line, dashed] (A) -- (G2);
\path [line, dashed] (G1) -- (B);
\path [line, dashed] (G2) -- (C);
\path [line, dashed] (B) -- (G1a);
\path [line, dashed] (B) -- (G1b);
\path [line, dashed] (C) -- (G2a);
\path [line, dashed] (C) -- (G2b);
\path [line] (G1a) -- (G1aD1);
\path [line] (G1b) -- (G1bD1); QQQ
\path [line] (G1aD1) -- (G1aD2);
\path [line] (G1bD1) -- (G1bD2);
\path [line] (G2a) -- (G2aD1);
\path [line] (G2b) -- (G2bD1);
\path [line] (G2aD1) -- (G2aD2);
\path [line] (G2bD1) -- (G2bD2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'd also suggest you try the `positioning` Ti*k*Z library, which is more modern and provides more convenient placement options than the default ones in Ti*k*z. After setting `node distance = 2cm` in the options of the `tikzpicture`, removing the `/tikz/auto` key that you don't use and the `arrows` Ti*k*Z library which is [deprecated according to master Schrödinger's cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521140/missing-node-when-using-tikz-package/521141?noredirect=1#comment1317810_521141)—I chose the `stealth` arrow tip—plus a bit more refactoring using `nodes=block, font=\itshape` and `\begin{scope}[every path/.append style={line}] ... \end{scope}`, etc. around the second part with all the `\path` commands, this gives the following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes}

\tikzset{
  decision/.style={
    diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node
    distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt},
  block/.style={
    rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text centered,
    rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
  line/.style={draw, -stealth},
}

\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, nodes=block, font=\itshape]

% Place nodes
\node (A) {Level A};
\node [left=of A] (G1) {\textbf{Group 1}};
\node [right=of A] (G2) {\textbf{Group 2}};
\node [below=of G1] (B) {Level B1};
\node [left=of B] (G1a) {\textbf{Group 1a}};
\node [below=of G1a] (G1aD1) {Decision 1};
\node [below=of G1aD1] (G1aD2) {Decision 2};
\node [below=of B] (G1b) {\textbf{Group 1b}};
\node [below=of G1b] (G1bD1) {Decision 1};
\node [below=of G1bD1] (G1bD2) {Decision 2};
\node [below=of G2] (C) {Level B2};
\node [left=of C] (G2a) {\textbf{Group 2a}};
\node [below=of G2a] (G2aD1) {Decision 1};
\node [below=of G2aD1] (G2aD2) {Decision 2};
\node [right=of C] (G2b) {\textbf{Group 2b}};
\node [below=of G2b] (G2bD1) {Decision 1};
\node [below=of G2bD1] (G2bD2) {Decision 2};

% Draw lines
\begin{scope}[every path/.append style={line}]
  \begin{scope}[every path/.append style={dashed}]
   \path (A) -- (G1);
   \path (A) -- (G2);
   \path (G1) -- (B);
   \path (G2) -- (C);
   \path (B) -- (G1a);
   \path (B) -- (G1b);
   \path (C) -- (G2a);
   \path (C) -- (G2b);
  \end{scope}
  \path (G1a) -- (G1aD1);
  \path (G1b) -- (G1bD1); QQQ
  \path (G1aD1) -- (G1aD2);
  \path (G1bD1) -- (G1bD2);
  \path (G2a) -- (G2aD1);
  \path (G2b) -- (G2bD1);
  \path (G2aD1) -- (G2aD2);
  \path (G2bD1) -- (G2bD2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As suggested by Schrödinger's cat, placing the nodes could be simplified using a `matrix of nodes` from the `matrix` Ti*k*Z library (you would still need to draw the arrows, of course). As I don't have anymore time tonight, this is left as an exercise to the reader. ;-)

Comment: I fully support the suggestion to load `postioning`, but I will upvote this answer only if you actually *use* it. (Sorry;-) That is, instead of e.g. `below of= G1aD1` you should say `below=of G1aD1` or `below=<distance> of G1aD1`, where `<distance>` is an appropriate distance. The `node distance` can then contain two values, e.g. `node distance=3em and 2em`, where the first value concerns vertical and the second horizontal distances. BTW, the `arrows` library is also deprecated (but IMHO not as much as the old-fashioned way of positioning things).

Comment: Thanks, will do. ;-) Also, `auto` is useless here, right?

Comment: Yes, at as long as you do not have edge labels it does not do anything. (You may simplify things by saying `nodes=block,text=\itshape` in the options of the `tikzpicture`, then you can drop all the `block,` and `\textit`s.) And you can avoid all the positioning by using a `matrix of nodes` (requires the `matrix` library).

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat I think that's `font=\itshape`, no?

Comment: Yes, `font=\itshape`

Comment: I guess eventually the OP will do this with forest because the intent seems to be to draw a tree (maybe).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  Yep yep, exercise to the reader or you ;-). Good night!

Comment: Thank you for helping me see where my error was!

Answer (score 4):

This is for fun: a version with `forest`. It does many of the things automatically. (@cfr could make it much more automatic, but this is what I got. ;-) The node contents are very repetitive and depend on the level, so does the style. Here the repeating node contents are added with `execute at begin node`, I will leave all the `content+` magic to users who can do such magic reliably.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
    Group/.style={block,font=\bfseries,execute at begin node={Group~}},
    Level/.style={block,font=\itshape,execute at begin node={Level~}},
    Decision/.style={block,execute at begin node={Decision~}},}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={if={level()>3}{Decision,edge={-stealth}}{%
        if={mod(level(),2)==0}{Level}{Group},edge={-stealth,dashed}},
    s sep+=1em,l sep+=1em}
[A
 [1
  [B1
   [1a[1[2]]]
   [1b[1[2]]]
  ]
 ]
 [2
  [B2
   [2a[1[2]]]
   [2b[1[2]]]
  ]
 ]
]   
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is elegant. Thank you.